# Python: extracting digits out of a string and performing a mathematical check

Tags: python

First post here.  I've tried researching quite a bit, but can't get exactly what I need. I'm sure it's simple.  I have a text string in format AxByCz, where ABC are letters (constant) while xyz are numbers that can change in magnitude.  I need to write a script that extracts the values of xyz, then checks to see if sum of y+z is equal to x.

For example, A321B300C21 is valid, while A15B12C9 is invalid.

I was able to extract integers if they're single digits (ie A5B2C3), but can't get it working if one of the numbers is double or more digits.

Don't need any fancy code or fancy libaries.

Thank you in advance for the help!

```
for a in batch:
        if  len(a)==5 and a[1]=="p" and a[3]=="d" and int(a[2])+int(a[4])==int(a[0]):
        elif  len(a)==5 and a[1]=="d" and a[3]=="p" and int(a[2])+int(a[4])==int(a[0]):
                print("works2")
```

Comment: `Don't need any fancy code or fancy libaries`. Not sure what this means or what you consider fancy, but it sounds like you need the regex (aka `re`) module from the standard library (that means, built into Python), which will do this in a single line. Is this for an assignment where that's not allowed?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the regex module (`re`), which isn't really a fancy module, because it is included standard library and you don't need to pip install it.

```
import re

string = "A321B300C21"
sub = re.search("^A\d+B\d+C\d+$", string)

if sub:
    xyz = re.findall("\d+", string)
    if int(xyz[0]) == int(xyz[1]) + int(xyz[2]):
        print("works")
    else:
        print("Doesn't work")
else:
    print("Not valid :(")
```

The code above is using regex to first validates if the string matches your format. If it does match your format, it gets all the three numbers and does the `x = y + z` check to see if it works.

Comment: @Mark Good point. You are right. Thank you. I have made the edits and fixed that.

Comment: Hi Amol, thanks much.  I'm just starting out, so trying to stay away from non-basic libraries.  I've seen regex come up in search results, but I don't really understand how they work.  Guess it's complicated to do via basic functions which is why it's been tough to find!  Thank you for the help though.